# return default value in Object

Tags: javascript, object

If I have a JS object like this:

```
myObject = {
  value: 'test value',
  editable: true
}
```

I want myObject to return `value` directly when requesting `myObject` in code, while still allowing `myObject.editable` to be accessed. 
I've tried looking into Getters but this doesn't seem to fit with what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: _requesting myObject_ ? How are you accessing it ? What have you tried so far ?

Comment: If you want `myObject` to return the string 'test value' and `myObject.editable` to return `true` at the save time, then I am sorry that is not possible as far as I know.

Comment: Rayon, just by calling `myObject`

Comment: I am getting downvotes on this question. Some people cannot handle exploring the edges of our beloved JS? If you downvote, please tell me why.

Comment: This is an interesting question, I've searched around for answers in the current versions of JavaScript/ES but a thought came to me. This would be very hard to read if it were a feature. The developer(s) would have zero context and this would probably lead a ton of issues. Imagine if you where to change the default value on an object that was a string to a complex object.Lots of side effects would  appear from that kind of change and a lot may not be seen. I think you're best bet is to come up with a pattern that's easy to follow. Use `value` property for example so you know thats your default

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is the equivalent of `toString` in Java or `__toString` in php. Unfortunately this *magic* function does not exist in javascript.

one simple workaround could be:

```
var myObject = function() {
  var _value: 'test value',
  var editable: true,

  // fluent get/set for value
  function value(value) {
    if(typeof value === 'undefined') {
      return _value;
    }
    _value = value;
    return this;
  }

  function isEditable() 
    return editable;
  }

  return {
    value: value,
    isEditable: isEditable
  }
}
```

so you can access the value via `myObject.value()` in your code

Comment: this still needs me to call `.value()`. I'd like to see the value directly when requesting `myObject`

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately there is no way in javscript to achieve what you want to do. My answer is just a workaround.